# Is there a built-in expression transformation which can perform this simplification?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an interval overlap test like this:

```
Min[a1, a2] <= b1 <= Max[a1, a2] || Min[a1, a2] <= b2 <= Max[a1, a2] ||
Min[b1, b2] <= a1 <= Max[b1, b2] || Min[b1, b2] <= a2 <= Max[b1, b2]
```

I know it can be rewritten as:

```
(a1 <= b1 || a1 <= b2 || a2 <= b1 || a2 <= b2) &&
(b1 <= a1 || b1 <= a2 || b2 <= a1 || b2 <= a2)
```

Is the a built-in expansion/simplification method for this? `PiecewiseExpand` and `Simplify` functions don't accomplish this.

My own solution is quite convoluted:

```
Or @@ Table[
     order && Refine[
       Min[a1, a2] <= b1 <= Max[a1, a2] || 
        Min[a1, a2] <= b2 <= Max[a1, a2] ||
        Min[b1, b2] <= a1 <= Max[b1, b2] || 
        Min[b1, b2] <= a2 <= Max[b1, b2], order],
     {order, And @@ (LessEqual @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]) & /@
       Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, {4}], 1]}] /.
   LessEqual -> le //
  BooleanMinimize[#, "CNF",
     Implies[And @@ (le @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1]), 
         le[First[#], Last[#]]] & /@
       Flatten[Permutations /@ Subsets[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, {3, 4}], 1] //
       Apply@And] /.
    le -> LessEqual & // Simplify
```

This can be broken into following parts:

- create an ORred expression of all variable orderings and their refined expressions for the test,
- convert this into a purely boolean expression whose variables are individual `LessEqual` tests of pairs of variables,
- perform Boolean CNF minimisation on this with a condition of implications on chained comparisons, and
- convert Boolean variables back to comparisons and run regular `Simplify` on this.

Answer (score 6):

Use FullSimplify with a penalty for the Cases of Min,Max

```
FullSimplify[
     LogicalExpand[
    Min[a1, a2] <= b1 <= Max[a1, a2] || 
    Min[a1, a2] <= b2 <= Max[a1, a2] || 
     Min[b1, b2] <= a1 <= Max[b1, b2] || 
    Min[b1, b2] <= a2 <= Max[b1, b2]], 
     ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] +10000 Count[#, Max[_] | Min[_],\[Infinity]]&)]

 a1 == b1 || a1 == b2 || a2 == b1 ||a2 == b2 || 
 (  a1 <= b2 ||
    a2 <= b1) && (a1 >= b1 || 
    a2 >= b2)) || 
    ((a1 <= b1 || a2 <= b2) && (a1 >= b2 || a2 >= b1))
```

Comment: I thought something like this probably helps, but it still has unnecessary equals comparisons, thus could be better. Not the first time `FullSimplify` missing somewhat obvious possibilities like these though...

Also, `LeafCount` of my result expression is 27, which is quite a bit less than 43 here. (Surely the above is already quite readable though.)